# Error not being thrown while reading a CSV when the decimal separator is not '.'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a csv in a flask app

I have a csv (`trial.csv`) as follows:

```
                 dates values
0  2020-01-01 00:15:00  0,154
1  2020-01-01 00:30:00  0,148
2  2020-01-01 00:45:00  0,141
```

I am reading the csv as follows:

```
from flask import abort
import pandas as pd

def csv_read(file):
    try:
        user_csv = pd.read_csv(file, decimal=".")
        return user_csv
    except ValueError:
        abort(400, 'Invalid decimal separator')
```

and I want to raise a 400 exception if the decimal separator in the `values` column is not `.`

But when I do:

```
csv_read('trial.csv')
```

instead of throwing the error, it reads the data and `return`s it..

What is the mistake i am doing?

Comment: the default separator for `read_csv` is `,`. You should pass some other separator, e.g.`sep='\t'`.

Comment: Also, even then, the function would still read the file without errors, and `values` column will be string type.

Comment: @QuangHoang My `values` column is a float. Is there a way where I can check if the `decimal`  is `.` or not and raise an error accordingly?

Comment: check out `parser` option in `read_csv`. It accepts a function which you can raise a `ValueError` to catch.

Comment: @QuangHoang I checked the documentation of `read_csv`, there is the only option of parsing date using the parameter `date_parser` and no option of `parser`

Comment: My bad. Then you can force dtype on `values` column with `dtype={'values':float}` option.